# how to get all elements in the document except those nested in a specific element?

Tags: xml, xpath

How to construct xPath on the following document

```
<TOP>
    <A>
        <AA>
            <AAA/>
        </AA>
    </A>
    <B>
        <BB>
            <BBB/>
        </BB>
    </B>
    <C>
        <CC>
            <CCC/>
        </CC>
    </C>
</TOP>
```

to select out:

```
A, AA, AAA, B, BB, BBB
```

All I wanted is to specify "C" in the xPath and the result will be "TOP//*" exclude "C" and all its children;

Comment: How is C different from A or B?

Comment: They look like they're structured exactly the same to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey they are differentiated from "Element Name" or "Tag Name". This is a very clear question, why you hold it?

Comment: Which is the element name, and which is the tag name?  I think you think it's clear, but the fact is that C is structured identically to A and B, so unless your assertion is that you want to simply exclude A and B by the names A and B, I don't think your question is clear at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Edited. the structure does not matter. I don't want "A" or "B" appear in the xPath; All I wanted is "C" appear in the xPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPATH you want is:

```
TOP/*[name() != 'C']/descendant-or-self::*
```

Comment: Excellent! Is this syntax supported by xPath 1.0?

Comment: @milesma This is why it is better to use actual examples, not made up ones. This question has answered the exact question you asked, it would be best to reask with the issue of namespaces included as the answer will likely be very different.